# Custom font not loading on WP site with promenade theme

Tags: wordpress, css, fonts, theme

I have a wordpress website using a custom audio theme (Promenade). I want to use my own font, so I uploaded the woff2 file to my folder and added the following code to the styles.css of the theme:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  src: url("https://molllust.com/wp-content/themes/promenade/fonts/OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; 
}
```

The font file is downloadable via the given address via browser. But the font doesn't seem to be downloaded at all. In the Chrome debugger, under **Network > Fonts** my font file isn't loaded. But in the same debugger, I can see the style.css is loaded with the @font-face line as it should. Other fonts seem to be loaded.

Do you have any idea, what might cause the font-file not being downloaded, though I checked the @font-face command a hundred times? The site is http://molllust.com

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the name of your font face, you need to use only a single value for the `font-family` directive. So, change

```
font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
```

to

```
font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
```

With `font-family` in `@font-face`, you're defining the name of your font family. It's different from when you use `font-family` elsewhere in your code, where you're providing the browser with a list of suitable fonts for rendering an element.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot :)